# Is gvm outdated?

Tags: go, gvm

The latest version `gvm listall` offers me is `go1.4`.

Am I missing something or is `gvm` outdated?

What's the recommended way to manage (potentially multiple) installations?

Comment: Also look at https://github.com/travis-ci/gimme

Comment: Interesting. At least  since it does  not conflict  with groovy  gvm.  Still, I wonder about  the motivation behind it  since most people seem to use  gvm.

Comment: Did you think about Vagrant to get isolated environment ?

Comment: "since most people seem to use gvm" … I very much doubt the accuracy of this statement; it's more likely a small minority of probably 10% at best (just going by some quick searches, github stars, etc).

Comment: I don't like Vagrant because its based on virtual machines which I find way to heavy for this kind of usage. I'd rather use a docker container (I am on Linux). My "most people" statement was based on a quick populartiy comparision of gimme vs. gvm on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, please update `gvm`. Also note, there are still some issues with Go1.5 and GVM, look at [github.com/moovweb/gvm/issues](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm/issues?q=is%3Aissue%201.5) for tips.

```
$ bash < <(curl -s -S -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moovweb/gvm/master/binscripts/gvm-installer)

$ source /Users/vasi/.gvm/scripts/gvm

$ gvm listall | grep 1.5
   go1.5
   go1.5beta1
   go1.5beta2
   go1.5beta3
   go1.5rc1
```

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like I have to resolve the conflict with groovy gvm again. :( https://github.com/moovweb/gvm/issues/103